# Kernel of a linear functional (definite integral)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need to find the Kernel of a linear functional, in this case the linear functional is a definite integral (I have already proved that a definite integral is linear).

I have F: R2[x] to R, defined by F(p) = $$\int_0^1 p(x) \,dx$$

I am suspecting that it has something to do with the annihilator subspace, but I cannot quite yet visualize how the solution should be. I am starting to get in this topic, and in internet I dont find enough information about this particular case of linear functionals.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the domain of the functional? Polynomials of degree $\le 2$?

Comment: Yes, R2[x]. Polynomials of degree 2 or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a straight line whose integral vanishes, take $x-1/2$ for example, and a quadratic, say $x^2-1/3$, which vanishes, too.  As the kernel can't have dimension $3$ and both functions are linearly independent, you've found a basis of the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Each polynomial in the domain can be written as $ax^2 + bx + c$ for some real numbers $a,b,c$. Write down the integral of this polynomial in terms of $a,b,c$, and see what you need for this integral to be zero.